# How can I pass client_id and client_secret in the body of the token exchange request using the react-native-app-auth package?

Tags: react-native, oauth, appauth

I am trying to use the otherwise excellent [react-native-app-auth](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth) to handle the OAuth part of an app I'm working on.

The server I am contacting expects to have the `client_id` and `client_secret` included in the body of the token exchange POST request, but it is not being included and therefore results always in a 401 unauthorised response.

I have tried many different config options as specified [in the docs](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth#config), such as passing the client_id and secret in `additionalParameters` and `customHeaders`.

```
// Passing this to the authorize method.
const config = {
            issuer: 'https://example.dev',
            clientId: client_id,
            clientSecret: client_secret
            redirectUrl: 'myapp://auth_success',
            scopes: scopes,
            serviceConfiguration: {
                tokenEndpoint: 'https://example.dev/access-token',
                authorizationEndpoint: `https://example.dev?`,
            }
```

Expected is a 200 response with a fresh auth and refresh token. Instead I get back "parameter "client_secret" and "client_id" is missing.

Comment: could you resolve it?